# HttpContextAccessor not returning logged in Windows User ID in ASP.NET MVC, what can be done?

Tags: userid, windows-identity

How can you get the current logged in Windows user id using HttpContextAccessor in ASP.NET MVC controller?

I tried to use HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) but doesn't return the User ID of the current logged in user.